# How to convert the hashmap value in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Consider the following json value:

```
{"Operator":{"DT5241":{"name":"LESLIE, Alec "},"DT3709":{"name":"DAWSON, Peter"},"DT4206":{"name":"PEPWORTH, Jasmine"}
```

How can I convert this to array?

I have tried doing this: Operator being my arr2[3]

```
var array = $.map(arr2[3], function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

But it does not help. It gives value as this:

```
0:Object
 DT5241:Object
 DT3709:Object
 DT4206:Object
```

I need only array list.

This works.
But its not inserting value to my table:

```
     var dataArray2 = [['TruckName', 'OperatorName']];
     for (var i = 3; i < arr2.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
     dataArray2.push([array[i], array[i].name]);
     }
```

Comment: why is java tagged ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `arr2[3]` is the object with 1 item that is the object with `Operator` key, so you need to iterate through `arr2[3].Operator`

```js
var arr2 = [];
arr2[3] = {
  "Operator": {
    "DT5241": {
      "name": "LESLIE, Alec "
    },
    "DT3709": {
      "name": "DAWSON, Peter"
    },
    "DT4206": {
      "name": "PEPWORTH, Jasmine"
    }
  }
}

var array = $.map(arr2[3].Operator, function(value, key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
});
console.log(array)
$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(array))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Doing this my DT5241 value disappears.

Comment: Please see my updated question, why is it not inserting the values to my dataArray2.